# R + ggplot: coordinate transforms and geom_fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code works well:

```
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))
p <- p + geom_tile(aes(fill=z))
p
```

It plots a nice heatmap. Here `df` contains `x` and `y`, created using `expand.grid()`, and `z` which contains the value at each (`x`,`y`) co-ordinate.

This code, on the other hand

```
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y))
p <- p + coord_map(project="lagrange")
p <- p + geom_tile(aes(fill=z))
p
```

doesn't plot anything much at all (and doesn't plot anything with all the coordinate transforms I've tried). My understanding is that the coord_map works on the x and y data, and the fill should be drawn on top of the transformed co-ordinates. However, this must be wrong as nothing's being plotted once the co-ordinates have been mapped to a new frame.

So my question is: how should I go about this so that it works properly? Could it be something to do with my data.frame `df`?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of ggplot2?

Comment: I'm using ggplot2_0.8.7, so... no. I'm not. update.packages() doesn't update the package, either. Will keep trying, and hopefully it will fix my problem...

Comment: OK, I've updated, now it's breaking all over the place. I'll ask a new question...

Comment: The question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522503/r-ggplot-update-problems-with-geom-tile

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in how the tile geom calculates the area it should cover interacting with the new coordinate system. I tried recreating your problem with this code.

```
vol.m <- melt(volcano)

#points & cartesian
p <- ggplot(vol.m, aes(X1, X2, color = value)) + geom_point()
#points and map
p + coord_map()

#hex & cartesian
p <- ggplot(vol.m, aes(X1, X2, fill = value)) + geom_hex(stat = "identity")
#hex & map
p + coord_map
```

I sat there for a while trying the same thing with `geom_tile()`, but it wouldn't plot, so I'll take your word for it that it doesn't work. Notice how the hexagons get all screwed up on the map coordinates. I guess when trying to plot tiles which have been calculated to fill the area, it can't tolerate plotting them on a different coordinate system.

**Edit:**
That is, changing the coordinate system merely changes the "graph paper" the plot is drawn on. So, if you computed a linear regression statistic, then changed the coordinates to be log-transformed, the plotted regression line would be bent. I'm guessing that `ggplot2` can't "bend" a tile to fit into a non-cartesian coordinate system.